# Calling convention which only allows one instance of a function at a time

Tags: c, calling-convention

Say I have multiple threads and all threads call the same function at approximately the same time.

Is there a calling convention which would only allow one instance of the function at any time? What I mean is that the function called by the second thread would only start after the function called by the first thread had returned.

Or are these calling conventions compiler specific? I don't have a whole lot of experience using them.

Comment: Are you asking about a [mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion)?  What does this question have to do with calling conventions?

Comment: Well I thought that calling conventions affected how the functions behaved on the stack so I was just wondering if one of them provided what I'm looking for here. But I must be wrong.

Comment: Calling conventions affect how parameters are pushed onto the stack and how they're retrieved, not how threads can call functions. You're looking for a mutex, critical section, or event. Search for `thread synchronization`, combined with whatever OS and language you're using.

Comment: Ok I've heard of critical sections before. Thanks.

Comment: Some very old CPUs often called functions in a non-reentrant way, e.g. storing args to some absolute address.  And/or editing the machine code of the callee to include the return address.  But these make reentrancy illegal (undefined behaviour), rather than serializing for you!  (And of course if some child function is calling back into a function, it can't wait for its parent to finish; that'll never happen.)  So yeah, seems nothing to do with non-reentrant calling conventions, just synchronization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Skip to the bottom if you don't care about the threading mumbo-jumbo)

As mentioned before, this is not a "calling convention" but a general problem of computing: [concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control). And the particular case where two or more threads can enter a shared zone at a time, and have a different outcome, is called a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) (and also extends to/from electronics, and other areas).

The hard thing about threading is that computing is such a deterministic affair, but when threading gets involved, it adds a degree of uncertainty, which vary per platform/OS.

A one-thread affair would guarantee that it can do all tasks in the same order, always, but when you got multiple threads, and the order depends on how fast they can complete a task, shared other applications wanting to use the CPU, then the underlying hardware affects the results.

There's not much of a "sure fire way to do threading", as there's techniques, tools and libraries to deal with individual cases.

## Locking in

The most well known technique is using semaphores (or locks), and the most well known semaphore is the mutex one, which only allows one thread at a time to access a shared space, by having a sort of "flag" that is raised once a thread has entered.

```
if (locked == NO)
{
    locked = YES;

    // Do ya' thing

    locked = NO;
}
```

The code above, although it looks like it could work, it would not guarantee against cases where both threads pass the `if ()` and then set the variable (which threads can easily do). So there's hardware support for this kind of operation, that guarantees that only one thread can execute it: The `testAndSet` operation, that checks and then, if available, sets the variable. ([Here's the x86 instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Test) from the [instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings))

On the same vein of locks and semaphores, there's also the read-write lock, that allows multiple readers and one writer, specially useful for things with low volatility. And there's many other variations, some that limit an X amount of threads and whatnot.

**But overall, locks are lame**, since they are basically forcing serialisation of multi-threading, where threads actually need to get stuck trying to get a lock (or just testing it and leaving). Kinda defeats the purpose of having multiple threads, doesn't it?

The best solution in terms of threading, is to minimise the amount of shared space that threads need to use, possibly, elmininating it completely. Maybe use `rwlocks` when volatility is low, try to have "try and leave" kind of threads, that check if the lock is up, and then go away if it isn't, etc.

As my OS teacher once said (in Zen-like fashion): "The best kind of locking is the one you can avoid".

## Thread Pools

Now, threading is hard, no way around it, that's why there are patterns to deal with such kind of problems, and the [Thread Pool Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) is a popular one, at least in iOS since the introduction of Grand Central Dispatch (GCD).

Instead of having a bunch of threads running amok and getting enqueued all over the place, let's have a set of threads, waiting for tasks in a "pool", and having queues of things to do, ideally, tasks that shouldn't overlap each other.

Now, the thread pattern doesn't solve the problems discussed before, but it changes the paradigm to make it easier to deal with, mentally. Instead of having to think about "threads that need to execute such and such", you just switch the focus to "tasks that need to be executed" and the matter of which thread is doing it, becomes irrelevant.

Again, pools won't solve all your problems, but it will make them easier to understand. And easier to understand may lead to better solutions.

All the theoretical things above mentioned are implemented already, at POSIX level (semaphore.h, pthreads.h, etc. pthreads has a very nice of r/w locking functions), try reading about them.

(Edit: I thought this thread was about Obj-C, not plain C, edited out all the Foundation and GCD stuff)

Answer (score 4):

[Calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) defines how stack & registers are used to implement function calls.  Because each thread has its own stack & registers, synchronising threads and calling convention are separate things.

To prevent multiple threads from executing the same code at the same time, you need a [mutex](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-posix2/).  In your example of a function, you'd typically put the mutex lock and unlock inside the function's code, around the statements you don't want your threads to be executing at the same time.

In general terms: Plain code, including function calls, does not know about threads, the operating system does.  By using a mutex you tap into the system that manages the running of threads.  More details are just a Google search away.

Note that [C11, the new C standard revision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29), does include multi-threading support.  But this does not change the general concept; it simply means that you can use C library functions instead of operating system specific ones.

Comment: @CarlNorum True, I've rephrased.